# Crear un script que genere un número random y que se cree un directorio con ese número y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a 1

Tags: bash, script, shell

> Crear un script donde se genere un número al azar y se creen directorios sucesivamente hasta llegar a 1
>
> Una vez generado el número, tenemos que crear un directorio raíz que se llame como

Esto es lo que llevo de ejerjicio y me da un error en la línea 11 (el segundo for).

Gracias

El código es

```
for i in $(($RANDOM%25));
do

    echo "este es tu numero" $i;
    mkdir $i


    for ((j=$i; j>0 j--))
    do
        mkdir $i

    done

done
```

Comment: Cuál error te da? Por favor, ve a [edit] tu pregunta y pon código y error como texto; nadie te va a responder con imagenes para ponerte a transcribir y los voluntarios acá normalmente replican tu problema (y para eso necesitan poder correr tu código). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Vale ahora la edito y la cambio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pongas los errores, ponlos completos, no es por molestar sino para que sea rápido decirte qué pasa. Se hace evidente el problema para todos si lo haces de esa forma.

Corriendo tu código, el error que se ve es

> $ sh pepito.sh
>
> pepito.sh: line 10: syntax error: arithmetic expression required
>
> pepito.sh: line 10: syntax error: `((j=$i; j>0 j--))'

Entonces, hay un problema en la expresión aritmética del for. En alguna.

Tu código tiene tres problemas. Uno, que al for le falta un punto y coma. Son tres expresiones aritméticas en el for (inicial, condición de parada, expresión de conteo).

Quedaría

```
for ((j=$i-1; j>0; j--))
```

El otro problema es que no estás haciendo nada para crear los directorios del for DENTRO del directorio que acabas de crear. Vas a obtener N directorios en el mismo lugar donde está el shell, todos al mismo nivel. Para eso, deberías decirle que cuando cree un directorio, **entre en él** antes de crear el siguiente.

El último problema es que comienzas el segundo for con j=i, así que vas a crear dos veces el directorio N, luego será el N-1, etc.

Eso resuelto quedaría más o menos así:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(($RANDOM%25));
do

    echo "este es tu numero" $i;
    mkdir $i
    cd $i

    for ((j=$i-1; j>0; j--))
    do
        mkdir $j
        cd $j
    done

done
```

Eso dará los directorios anidados que buscas, hasta 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias, perdón es que soy nuevo en esto

Comment: @Juan con gusto, no hay lío que todos vamos aprendiendo cosas. Lo importante es que te permitas ser guiado por los comentarios que te dejan para que te podamos responder rápidamente. Revisa los enlaces y tal. Y si mi respuesta te resolvió el problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que otros sepan cómo resolver esta duda en el futuro (tick a la izquierda de la respuesta, junto a los votos)

Comment: No encuentro lo de marcar como completada

Comment: @Juan Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.